# Issue in compiling Faster RNNLM in Windows

Tags: c++, linux, templates, visual-studio-2012, eigen3

I am trying to compile Faster RNNLM in Visual Studio 2012.
https://github.com/yandex/faster-rnnlm

The issue is that it uses some templated functions from Eigen library which I am not able to compile in VS (although its compiling perfectly in Linux/Cygwin) . To be specific, the functions is:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> RowMatrix;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Real, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> RowVector;

template<int rows>
inline void Dump(const Eigen::Matrix<Real, rows, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>& matrix, FILE* fo) {
  fwrite(matrix.data(), sizeof(Real), matrix.rows() * matrix.cols(), fo);
}


template<int rows>
inline void Load(Eigen::Matrix<Real, rows, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>* matrix, FILE* fo) {
  FreadAllOrDie(
      matrix->data(), sizeof(Real), matrix->rows() * matrix->cols(), fo,
      "failed to read matrix");
}

template<class Matrix>
void DumpMatrixArray(std::vector<Matrix*> array, FILE* fo) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
    Dump(*array[i], fo);
  }
}


template<class Matrix>
void LoadMatrixArray(std::vector<Matrix*> array, FILE* fo) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
      Load(array[i], fo);
  }
}
```

The error I am getting during compilation is:

```
Error   112 error C2784: 'void Dump(const Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> &,FILE *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> &' from 'RowMatrix'    
Error   35  error C2784: 'void Dump(const Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> &,FILE *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> &' from 'const RowMatrix'
Error   115 error C2784: 'void Load(Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> *,FILE *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> *' from 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols> *'
Error   19  error C2784: 'void Load(Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> *,FILE *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix<Real,rows,-1,1> *' from 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols,_Options> *'
```

I created a small code tounderstand the issue in details. This code compiles perfectly when I call the Dump with number of rows like `Dump<5>(rm, temp)`. But I can not use this in actual code as the number of rows is not known at compile time.
The sample code that I have is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

typedef float Real;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> RowMatrix;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Real, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> RowVector;
template<int rows>
inline void Dump(const Eigen::Matrix<Real, rows, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>& matrix, FILE* fo) {
  fwrite(matrix.data(), sizeof(Real), matrix.rows() * matrix.cols(), fo);
}


template<int rows>
inline void Load(Eigen::Matrix<Real, rows, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>* matrix, FILE* fo) {
  FreadAllOrDie(
      matrix->data(), sizeof(Real), matrix->rows() * matrix->cols(), fo,
      "failed to read matrix");
}

inline void FreadAllOrDie(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE* fo, const char* message) {
  size_t read = fread(ptr, size, count, fo);
  if (read != count) {
    fprintf(
        stderr, "ERROR: expected to read %zu elements, but read %zu elements (%s)\n",
        count, read, message);
    exit(1);
  }
}

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    RowMatrix rm;
    FILE* temp = fopen("temp", "wb");
    rm.resize(5,5);
    Dump(rm, temp);
    MatrixXd m = MatrixXd::Random(3,3);  
    m = (m + MatrixXd::Constant(3,3,1.2)) * 50; 
    cout << "m =" << endl << m << endl;  
    VectorXd v(3);  
    v << 1, 2, 3;  
    cout << "m * v =" << endl << m * v << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and why the code is compiling and working in Linux/Cygwin but not in VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of rows in not known at compile time, you can't use that number as a template argument. Templates are instantiated at compile time so a call like:

```
Dump<5>(rm, temp);
```

will work whereas a call like

```
int five = 5;
Dump<five>(rm, temp);
```

will not. Regarding Eigen, if the number of rows at compile time is not known, then the number of rows is represented as `Eigen::Dynamic` or `-1`. The compiler may/should be able to deduce this as the `RowMatrix` is just a typedef for `Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>`. If it doesn't, you can try and force the issue by using

```
Dump<rm.RowsAtCompileTime>(rm, temp);
```

Comment: But the issue is the code is compiling without any issue in Cygwin. its giving error only in VS. so I assume it has to do something with VS which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: As I mentioned, the compiler (cl.exe) is for some reason, not correctly deducing the template arguments even though the information is provided within `rm`. This is just one of the quirks of Visual Studio. There are many questions asking "Why doesn't VS correctly deduce the template arguments" where the answer is, essentially, "compiler bug."